# Background Image is Repeated

Tags: vb.net, opengl

I want to show a background image before I draw my objects in the scene. When my opengl window loads it shows the background image repeated. I did some testing and if I keep my viewport X,Y dimensions at 0 and 1 then the background image is shown correctly.

```
Private _vXmin As Double = 0
Private _vXmax As Double = 1
Private _vYmin As Double = 0
Private _vYmax As Double = 1
Private _vZmin As Double = 0
Private _vZmax As Double = 1

Private Sub SetupViewport()
    Dim w As Integer = Me.Width
    Dim h As Integer = Me.Height
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)
    GL.LoadIdentity()
    GL.Ortho(_vXmin, _vXmax, _vYmin, _vYmax, _vZmin, _vZmax)
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, w, h)
End Sub
```

The problem is that my drawing objects are outside this narrow view space. So I resize my viewport to something more along the lines of 0->2000 to accommodate all the vertices...

```
    _vXmin = 0
    _vXmax = 2000
    _vYmin = 0
    _vYmax = 2000
    _vZmin = -1
    _vZmax = 1
```

Hence the background image is repeated, because it wants to remain size 0->1. Is there someway around this? Or am I fundamentally doing my object drawing incorrectly by changing the viewport to be larger than 1? Do I need to change all my vertices to live between -1 to 1?

EDIT #1

My code to set the background image. FYI, I got this online somewhere. I'm not 100% on what is going on here.

```
' Set Background Image
Private Function SET_BACKGROUND_IMG() As Integer
    Dim myImg As String = "C:\Users\00835182\Documents\Programs\OpenGL\_background_color.jpg"
    Dim id As Integer = GL.GenTexture
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, id)
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, TextureMinFilter.Linear)
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, TextureMagFilter.Linear)
    Dim bmp = New Bitmap(myImg)
    Dim bmp_data As BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, bmp_data.Width, bmp_data.Height, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bmp_data.Scan0)
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmp_data)
    Return id
End Function
```

And finally, my code to render the background image.

```
' Render Background
Private Sub RENDER_BACKGROUND()
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D)
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, _img)
    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads)
    GL.TexCoord2(_vXmin, _vYmin)
    GL.Vertex2(_vXmin, _vYmin)
    GL.TexCoord2(_vXmax, _vYmin)
    GL.Vertex2(_vXmax, _vYmin)
    GL.TexCoord2(_vXmax, _vYmax)
    GL.Vertex2(_vXmax, _vYmax)
    GL.TexCoord2(_vXmin, _vYmax)
    GL.Vertex2(_vXmin, _vYmax)
    GL.End()
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0)
    GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D)
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you drawing your background ? You render it on a quad ? Have you defined the uv coordinates of this quad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the issue. The solution is simple.

Firstly note that the texture size is (0.0, 0.0) to (1.0, 1.0) in OpenGL regardless of the viewport or texture image dimensions. since you are drawing a quad here is an example of how it works.

```
Texture coords              : Output
(0.0, 0.0) - (1.0, 1.0) : texture spans across the whole quad once.
(0.0, 0.0) - (2.0, 2.0) : texture spans in a 2/2 grid across the quad.
```

hence the texture beyond 1.0 will repeat itself. You can also use 0.5 to use only half a texture. or 3.0 to repeat the texture 3 times in a dimension. Play with the range and you will understand how it works.

so if you want your texture to span across the whole viewport once, here is a modified version of your code.

```
GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads)
GL.TexCoord2d(0.0, 0.0)
GL.Vertex2(_vXmin, _vYmin)
GL.TexCoord2d(1.0, 0.0)
GL.Vertex2(_vXmax, _vYmin)
GL.TexCoord2d(1.0, 1.0)
GL.Vertex2(_vXmax, _vYmax)
GL.TexCoord2d(0.0, 1.0)
GL.Vertex2(_vXmin, _vYmax)
GL.End()
```

Cheers.

Comment: That makes sense, however, I changed my code to this and it isn't rendering any differently. It is still (stubbornly) rendering the same repeated texture. BTW, I changed the xMax, yMax to be 1.0, 1.0 - you have it as 1.0, 0.0. Also, I changed the TexCoord2 coordinates to several different values to see the effects and every time it rendered the exact same background image repeated in the same way. Any other suggestions ??? I'm all ears.

Comment: Just to be clear you are changing your orthogonal matrix and not the gl viewport which is (0, 0, w, h) right? Its possible the problem is elsewhere in your code. If changing the tex coords makes no difference, then its not the quad you are seeing in your output.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it or not... I have a similar program on my home computer with the same issues. Again, I used your suggestion, however, this time I used integers not floats (no decimal) and IT WORKED! I didn't think the decimal would be the issue. I have to try again on my work machine, but this may be the answer I was looking for.

Comment: OMG Ok. I got the problem. I overlooked that fact that you used glTexCoord2() instead of glTexcoord2d(). Ok the former is for integers and the latter is for doubles. Corrected in the answer. Please make the change. Alternatively for `floats` (aka `Single` in vb) you can use glTexCoord2f(). Good Luck. Refer this link for more info opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml – Harish